# Python permutation within a group

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of the list within the group using the itertools.

`itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`

For example, I have a CSV file that contains :

```
customerID,storeID
C1,S1 
C1,S2 
C1,S3 
C2,S1 
C2,S2 
C2,S4 
C2,S5
```

The output I am after is the all possible combination of storeIDs that each customer can have. For example,

```
C1, S1, S2
C1, S1, S3
C1, S2, S3
C2, S1, S2
C2, S1, S4
C2, S1, S5
C2, S2, S4
C2, S2, S5
C2, S4, S5
```

I can easily get the entire combination of the storeIDs but not quite sure how to do it within the group only.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your csv is already sorted. If this is the case, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to grab the elements grouped by the first column:

```py
import csv
from itertools import combinations, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('myfile.csv') as fh:
    # skip header
    _ = next(fh)

    reader = csv.reader(fh)

    # itemgetter(0) will grab the first element as the grouping key
    for k, v in groupby(reader, key=itemgetter(0)):
        chunk = [item[1] for item in v]
        group = list(combinations(chunk, 2))
        print(k, group)

C1 [('S1 ', 'S2 '), ('S1 ', 'S3 '), ('S2 ', 'S3 ')]
C2 [('S1 ', 'S2 '), ('S1 ', 'S4 '), ('S1 ', 'S5'), ('S2 ', 'S4 '), ('S2 ', 'S5'), ('S4 ', 'S5')]
```

If it's unsorted, you can still do the same, but use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to hold your entries:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby, combinations
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

groups = defaultdict(list)

with open('myfile.csv') as fh:
    # skip header
    _ = next(fh)

    reader = csv.reader(fh)

    # itemgetter(0) will grab the first element as the grouping key
    for k, v in groupby(reader, key=itemgetter(0)):
        chunk = [item[1] for item in v]
        group = list(combinations(chunk, 2))
        groups[k].extend(group)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C1': [('S1 ', 'S2 '), ('S1 ', 'S3 '), ('S2 ', 'S3 ')], 'C2': [('S1 ', 'S2 '), ('S1 ', 'S4 '), ('S1 ', 'S5'), ('S2 ', 'S4 '), ('S2 ', 'S5'), ('S4 ', 'S5')]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to take care of this using pandas

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customerID':['C1','C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'], 'storeID': ['S1','S2','S3','S1','S2','S4','S5']})
output_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range( len(set(df['customerID']))):

    iter_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['customerID', 'store1', 'store2'])

    customerID = list(set(df['customerID']))[i]

    #get subset of stores for this customer
    temp_df = df[df['customerID'] == customerID]

    #stores of interest
    stores = list(set(temp_df['storeID']))

    for item in itertools.combinations(stores, r=2):
        iter_df.loc[len(iter_df)] = [customerID, item[0], item[1]]

    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, iter_df])


output_df = output_df.sort_values(by = ['customerID'])
```

you would loop through the dataframe and subset it each time, and for each subset create combinations